# My roommate accidentally(?) left the stove on. Should I be concerned?

Tags: safety, gas, stove

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but it's somewhat of a safety question, so here goes...

I came home from work the other day and saw there was a pot on the stove. Thinking one of my roommates got home before me, I thought nothing of it. After a while though, I realized that I was the only one home. After taking a closer look, I saw that the pot was completely empty, sitting on a gas burner adjusted to the low setting. I shut it off, put the pot in the sink (which sizzled when I doused it with water), and saw that the bottom of the pot had been warped due to the heat.

Most likely, someone turned the knob the wrong way by accident when they shut the burner off. However, the paranoid side of me is thinking "sabotage". Is coming home to a burner set on low something to be suspicious about? Even if it was an accident, what harm could there be from having a burner running this way unattended for hours (excluding the waste of gas or the risk of fire, I'm thinking along the lines of gas leak or something nonobvious)? Is there a legitimate use for doing that, such as heating a pot of water to humidify the room?

Comment: Your roommate left an empty preheating pot or a pot of water on the stove and forgot about it. This question has nothing to do with home improvement, except for the side question of "Is leaving a gas stove on low for an extended period of time harmful?" Voting to close.

Comment: "the paranoid side of me is thinking 'sabotage'" this sounds more like an inter-personal issue with your roommate more than a DIY question. :)

Comment: It was a mistake to put it in water - you should have just let it cool slowly. The shock of water can warp the metal.

Comment: To answer your question: Running a flame on low for extended time is safe.

Comment: @Ariel *probably* safe. However, in a very small space, with no ventilation, there could be a chance of carbon monoxide build up. But most spaces should have enough ventilation that a burner wouldn't pose a serious risk.

Comment: @DA01 If that was a problem then there would be a problem simply *using* the fire. If you can safely use the fire actively, you can safely leave it on low for extended time.

Comment: @Ariel most cooking is temporary--for minutes at a time, rather than hours. There is certainly a relation to time and hazard. This is why unvented gas heaters are not recommended--because they naturally need to burn for much longer amounts of time.

Comment: @DA01 I guess you've never made a large meal? People cook on high for hours all the time. I understand your point about venting! Don't think I don't. But if your home is so poorly vented you can not leave it on low for hours you should not be using it at *all*.

Comment: @Ariel in colder climates it's not unusual to hear a story or two each winter of a family getting really sick due to using a gas range as a heater. It happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only risk is the obvious damage to the pan, and the risk of whatever was in the pan catching fire and creating a lot of smoke, or possibly igniting surrounding materials.  If they meant you harm, they would have left the burner on without lighting it.

Comment: except modern day stoves automatically shut off the gas when it's not lit

Comment: It's the opposite of the AI apocalypse: the machines will rise up and... not kill us due to all of the built-in safety features.

Comment: One other risk: If it's a teflon pot, heating it sans contents can allow off-gassing, which isn't good for you, and it can deteriorate the coating to the point where it may start coming off in food. As the pot is warped, it's likely in the trash already so no big deal. But in general, if a teflon pan is accidentally overheated empty, it's probably time to trash it.

Comment: It's stainless steel. The bottom panel is apparently separate from, and welded to, the interior piece (so the interior bottom is still flat). It's only slightly warped and still usable. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: @DA01 The stuff about teflon is a bit misleading - oil will emit toxic gasses at a lower temperature than teflon. I've seem people not use teflon pans to protect birds, which is a mistake since the hot oil is more toxic for them than teflon.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Only the oven does that, the stovetop does not. (If you know of a stovetop that does, please show me - I've never seen any stovetop do that.)

Comment: @Ariel I think there's certainly an amount of FUD surrounding the topic, but at a basic level, it's not a good idea to super heat empty teflon cookware.

Comment: @ratchetfreak:  We have a new natural gas stove, a [GE Profile](http://products.geappliances.com/ApplProducts/Dispatcher?REQUEST=SpecPage&Sku=P2B940DEHBB).  It is easy to turn the gas on to a burner without lighting it–just turn the knob fast so it doesn't have time for the igniter to spark.  It will free flow gas until turned off.